# Where to call SDK.init() in Azure DevOps extension? componentWillMout() will be deprecated

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

There is a call to `SDK.init()` in `componentWillMount()` in many Azure DevOps extension samples.

For example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/master/src/Samples/RepositoryServiceHub/RepositoryServiceHub.tsx):

```
public async componentWillMount() {
    SDK.init();
    const repoSvc = await SDK.getService<IVersionControlRepositoryService>(GitServiceIds.VersionControlRepositoryService);
}
```

But `componentWillMount()` is [deprecated now](https://blog.northcoders.com/react-componentwillmount-to-be-deprecated). So where am I supposed to place this code?

Notice: I am also missing `await` when calling `SDK.init()` in this example. I suppose that it should be there.

Comment: How about call `SDK.init()` in `componentDidMount()`? According the document you provided it recommended use the `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()`. like: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sample/blob/2918009544bf3c39ceb2d86e79bcca41a78528ad/src/Samples/WorkItemFormGroup/WorkItemFormGroup.tsx#L24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research of some existing plugins, there is a better way than move `SDK.init()` to `componentDidMount`:

I found the best way where to init [in this plugin from Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-repos-pr-multi-cherry-pick/blob/master/src/app.ts). Simply put `SDK.init()` into your `app.ts`

```
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";

SDK.init();
```